# Can two consumers get same set of messages while retrieving messages using an Pull based Manner?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging

So I have a one client-server based ecosystem where I am using RabbitMQ as a persistent Middleware.

Now the flow of a single message goes like this.

- Step-1: Client A sends a message to the server with the destination
  being set to Client B in the metadata of that message.
- Step-2: Server upon receiving a message pushes the message to the
  RabbitMQ and sends Client B a notification that he has some messages
  to fetch.
- Step-3: Client B upon getting notified calls the fetch message API to
  get messages from the server.
- Step-4: On the server, after getting called from the Client B pulls
  messages from the RabbitMQ using the pull-based approach
  (`channel.basicGet(queueName, false)`) and hands over the list of
  messages.

Now in the above flow, there are few things that I have some doubt with.

First of all, if my client receives two notifications and calls the pull message API twice, there might be a concurrency problem.

Suppose I am not sending the message Acknowledgement while getting the message but I am sending afterwards, then can It be possible that the same message being sent to two pull API? If so is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Sample Code to Get Message From the MQ:

```
    long currentMessageCount = channel.messageCount(QUEUE_NAME);
    while (currentMessageCount-- > 0) {
        GetResponse getResponse = channel.basicGet(QUEUE_NAME, false);
        if (getResponse == null) {
            break;
        }
        AMQP.BasicProperties props        = getResponse.getProps();
        Envelope             envelope     = getResponse.getEnvelope();
        int                  messageCount = getResponse.getMessageCount();
        byte[]               body         = getResponse.getBody();
        /*
            Do some logic
         */
        channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

`basicGet` is rarely the correct solution. In Step 2, the client should be consuming from RabbitMQ. No notification that a message is ready is necessary. RabbitMQ will send the message to Client B as soon as it's in the queue. Step-3 and Step-4 become unnecessary.

Comment: I have a messaging app.. that gets a notification from the server.. and then it's pulling from the server... I have no choice other than a pull based mechanism.. otherwise I should've used push based one..

Comment: "I have no choice other than a pull based mechanism" - based on your description, I disagree.